# Plotting two graphs in parallel

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using subfigure to plot two graphs in parallel but somehow graphs get plotted vertically.

```
 \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[c]{.49\linewidth}
            \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                grid=major,
                xlabel=Training examples,
                ylabel=Score,
                ymin=0.0, ymax=1.0,
                xtick={50,100,...,400},
                enlarge x limits=true]

            \addplot[color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
            (42, 0.84403119)  
            (105,0.86293386) 
            (168,0.87034796)
            (230,0.86521767) 
            (294,0.86666055) 
            (357,0.86770618) 
            (420, 0.86720932)
};

            \addplot[color=black,mark=x] coordinates {
            (42, 0.3107208)  
            (105, 0.34249718) 
            (168,0.34461004)
            (230,0.38054631) 
            (294,0.38010474) 
            (357,0.38951365) 
            (420, 0.39468893)
};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \caption{Note the semilogarithmic axes.}
        \label{Fig:Sample_Subfig1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            grid=major,
            xlabel=Training examples,
            ylabel=Score,
            ymin=0.0, ymax=1.0,
            xtick={50,100,...,400},
            enlarge x limits=true]

            \addplot[color=black,mark=*] coordinates {
            (42, 0.91991749)  
            (105,0.93808971) 
            (168,0.94794605)
            (230,0.94909335) 
            (294,0.95022338) 
            (357,0.94868243) 
            (420, 0.94911792)
};
            \addplot[color=black,mark=x] coordinates {
            (42, 0.43461714)  
            (105, 0.47933351) 
            (168,0.51750528)
            (230,0.52896894) 
            (294,0.54132926) 
            (357,0.53517943) 
            (420, 0.54815149)
};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }


    \caption{Two chain growth probabilities.}
    \label{Fig:Sample_Subfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Sample of how to use subfigures.}
\label{Fig:Theo_SFDev}
\end{figure}
```

[image: ra]

Comment: That is probably because you write `\end{subfigure} <newline> <newline>\begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth}` in your example write `\end{subfigure}%<newline>\begin{subfigure}` or put `%` at the end of every line between `\end{subfigure}` (included) and `\begin{subfigure}`.

Comment: it worked, thanks  @BambOo

Comment: Just to clarify a bit my comment, when you jump lines, Latex basically inserts a new paragraph. So you have to force it to think both subfigures should be in the same line. Think of these as two characters. You would not put a blank line between them

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments